# Swift EXC_BREAKPOINT while looking a file on iphone. Works on one iPhone but not on other iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I'm having a weird error with Swift and I have no idea why and how to solve it

The code:

```
var bool = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileToOpen, ofType: "txt", inDirectory: "levels"))
    println("Bool : \(bool)")
    if(bool){
        let pathToFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileToOpen, ofType: "txt", inDirectory: "levels")
        let fileInfo = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(pathToFile, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: error)
        var textArray = [String]()
        println(fileInfo)
```

The Error:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
```

The problem:

This code works perfectly fine on my iPhone 5S, but when I try this code on an iPhone 4S it crashes at the first line (`var bool = NSFileManager.defaultMan...`)
I know though that there does exists a file because the bool returns true and on my iPhone 5S the code works, I also know that even though it says that there is an exception at the `var bool` line there are still segments of the code behind that line that are still executed for example the `println(fileInfo)` is still executed. So I assume that even though the first line of the code does get the exception, the error isn't there? Anyone has an idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

More info:

using xcode 6-beta 3
iphone 5s is on 7.1.2
iphone 4s is on 7.1

Answer (score 4):

Solved the problem.
The problem was a bit further in the code where I used `arc4random % number`
I changed it to `arc4random_uniform(UInt32(number))` and the error dissapeared

Comment: This worked for me don't know why this cause error on different line. (pewh)